# Show that the graph of f(x) is closed

Tags: general-topology

I am working through Mendelson's Introduction to Topology Third edition and I am stuck on Exercise 4 from Chapter 2 Section 6. Specifically, I don't know how to show that the graph is closed. I have been using proof wiki to help me out with these problems, and the [given proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Mapping_whose_Graph_is_Closed_in_Chebyshev_Product_is_not_necessarily_Continuous) mostly makes sense to me (though I suspect it is riddled with typos). I cannot understand their argument for $(0,0)$.

Here is the text from the question:

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x}, \text{ } x > 0 \\
0, \text{ } x \leq 0
\end{cases}
$.

Prove that the graph $\Gamma_{f}$ is a closed subset of $\left( \mathbb{R}^2,d\right)$, but that $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: It might be easier to note that $\operatorname{graph} f = \{ (x,y) | x \ge 0, xy=1 \} \cup \{(x,y) | x \le 0, y = 0 \}$, the union of two closed sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $(x_n, f(x_n)) \to (x,y)$. If $x >0$ the $x_n >0$ for $n$ sufficiently large and $f(x_n)=\frac  1 {x_n} \to y$ Also, $\frac  1{x_n} \to \frac 1  x$.  So $y=\frac 1 x$ and $(x,y)=(x,f(x))$ which belongs to then graph.

If $x<0$ then $x_n <0$ for $n$ sufficiently large  and $0=f(x_n) \to y$. Thus, $y=0=f(x)$ and $(x,y)=(x,f(x))$ belongs to the graph.

Now let $x=0$ so that $x_n \to 0$ and $f(x_n) \to 0$. If $x_n >0$ for infinitely many values of $n$ then $f(x_n)=\frac  1 {x_n}$ for such $n$  but then $(f(x_n))$ is unbounded along this subsequenece. This contradicts converegence of $f(x_n)$ to $y$ (:convegent sequences are bounded). So we must have $x_n \leq 0$ for all $n$ sufficiently large.

Now $0=f(x_n) \to y$ so $y=0$ and $(x,y)=(x,f(x))$ which is in the graph.

Comment: Thank you! This was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It should be $f\colon\mathbb{R}_0^+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, when only defined for $x\geq 0$. We have $\Gamma_f=\{(x,y)\in{\mathbb{R}^+}^2|y=\frac{1}{x}\}\cup\{(0,0)\}$. Obviously the second set $\{(0,0)\}$ is closed, because for a point $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$ and $0<r<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ we have an open neighborhood $B_r(x,y)$ around it. The first set (Let's call it $A$.) is also closed, here are two ways to prove it:

Let $(x,y)\in{\mathbb{R}^+}^2$ with $y\neq\frac{1}{x}$ and $0<\varepsilon<\frac{1}{2}\left|y-\frac{1}{x}\right|$. Because $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^+$, there exists a $\delta>0$ so that for all $x'\in\mathbb{R}^+$ with $|x-x'|<\delta$, we have $\left|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x'}\right|<\varepsilon$. Now $B_{\min\{\delta,\varepsilon\}}(x,y)$ is an open neighborhood around $(x,y)$.

Let $(x,y)\in\overline{A}$, then there exists a sequence $(x_n,y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset A$ with $(x_n,y_n)\rightarrow(x,y)$. The first condition means that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\colon y_n=\frac{1}{x_n}$. Using the Heine theorem (continuous functions like $f$ preserve limits), we get $y_n=\frac{1}{x_n}=f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\stackrel{!}{=}y$, where the latter holds since limit points are unique in Hausdorff spaces. Therefore $(x,y)\in A$.